# MySql query on combination of AND and OR

Tags: mysql

I want to write a MySql query whereby I want to use combination of AND and OR. I have 6 attributes where in I want one String to appear AND there is one attribute in which a compulsory thread should appear.

My command looks like this.

```
Select * from Students where roll_no like '__2011%' and subject1 ='maths' or subject2='maths' or subject3='maths' or subject4='maths' or subject5='maths' or subject6='maths';
```

I want 'maths' to appear in atleast one of those subject attributes. Along with that Roll no should have 2011 in it as specified in the query.
Please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Select * from Students where roll_no like '__2011%' and (subject1 ='maths' or subject2='maths' or subject3='maths' or subject4='maths' or subject5='maths' or subject6='maths');
```

Comment: I need atleast 15 reputation to do that. But anyway, I have posted it as useful one. Thanks a lot. I didn't know that one could place brackets there like that. :)

Comment: An explanation would be helpful to future readers. What did you change and how does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

When you have multiple `or` conditions, [`in`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) is a cleaner way to handle this:

```
Select * 
from Students 
where 
    roll_no like '__2011%' and 
    'maths' in (subject1, subject2, subject3, subject4, subject5, subject6);
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit faster than multiple "or"

```
select * from students where roll_no like '__2011%' and
 concat_ws(' ',subject1,subject2,subject3,subject4,subject5,subject6) like '%maths%'
```

Comment: Hi, your code is working fine. But the problem is I have to give it as '%maths%'. If I give it as 'maths', it gives me  wrong answer. Atleast, I have to keep one % symbol on either side to make the code work. But what if, I had something like 'Maths A','Maths' and 'A Maths' and I wanted only 'Maths' to come up, how do I work around in that situation? Also, in concat_ws, what is the first parameter where you have left one empty ' '?  I liked your solution but.