# Where clause in PHP MySQL not working with Like keyword

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to filter my data according to the c_type = "Engineering' and search keyword in the search box. The searching part is working fine but the query is not working it displays the whole result.

This is for filtering my result

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM col_details WHERE c_type = 'Engineering' and c_name LIKE '%{$name}%' OR location LIKE '%{$name}%' ");
```

I am trying to display all the results in my col_details table with c_type is Engineering and c_name or location is taken from the Search Box.
The search box code is working fine but it's displaying all data and not the data with c_type = 'Engineering'.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the way you use `and` and `or` together - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640122/mysql-query-on-combination-of-and-and-or may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **OR** clause should be wrapped in brackets, 
Try this:

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM col_details WHERE c_type = 'Engineering' and (c_name LIKE '%{$name}%' OR location LIKE '%{$name}%') ");
```

Hope it helps.